# компонент "загруженности" в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не могу сообразить, как правильно сделать следующую задачку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть полоса. Она занимает 100% шириины. В этой полосе есть три статуса заказа: в ожидании, активные, выполненные.

Как правильно заполнять эту полосу в зависимости от кол-ва статуса заказов? Если в статусе заказов 0, то и заполнять этим цветом полосу не надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я бы делал примерно таким способом

```js
function App() {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState({pending: 5, active: 2, completed: 1})

  const countTotalOrders = () => {
    return Object.keys(data).reduce((s, c) => {
      return s + data[c];
    }, 0);
  }

  const countWidth = (field) => {
    return (data[field] / countTotalOrders()) * 100;
  }

  return (
    <div style={{
      display: 'flex',
      width: '100%',
      height: '15px',
      background: 'grey'
    }}>
      <div style={{
        width: `${countWidth('pending')}%`,
        height: '100%',
        background: 'red'
      }}></div>
      <div style={{
        width: `${countWidth('active')}%`,
        height: '100%',
        background: 'blue'
      }}></div>
      <div style={{
        width: `${countWidth('completed')}%`,
        height: '100%',
        background: 'lightgrey'
      }}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо. А можете подсказать еще, что мы делаем вот в этом моменте:

(s + data[c])

Comment: WoodRest, data[c] возвращает значение текущего ключа в переборе и суммирует его с предыдущим значением. Почитайте как работает метод reduce